# sending json to the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The json structure in the database will look like this: I want to send data to it, can I do it this way?

```
{
    "Name":"Name",
    "Description":"Description",
    "PointList" :
    [{
        "Name": "Name",
        "X": 0.5,
        "Y": 0.8,
        "RouteId": 1,
        "Description":"ds"
         },]
}
```

How to build newItem to send json to the database correctly?

```
 const newItem = {
      "Name": this.state.Name,
      "Description": this.state.Description,
      "PointList": [this.state.Name, parseFloat(this.state.X), parseFloat(this.state.Y), this.state.Description],
      "Y": parseFloat(this.state.X),
      "X": parseFloat(this.state.Y),
    };
    fetch("http://dearjean.ddns.net:44301/api/Points3/Add", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newItem)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
  };
```

When I send it this way, the console shows me:
{Points3s: Array(0), route: {…}} - table is empty ...

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete example of post call using fetch. Please have a look.

```
import React from "react";
const Form = () => {
    const submission = {
        title: 'This is title',
        body: 'This is body',
        userId: 1
    };
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(submission),
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response, 'response');
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log("not ok" + response.status);
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };

    return <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click here to submit</button>;
};

export default Form
```

Answer (score -1):

In the `PointList` array in the `newItem` object, there's no key. You have only the value. But in the above expected `JSON`, there's key in the object.

For posting, you can use AXIOS library. Something like the below:

```
const newTodo = {
  todo_description: this.state.todo_description,
  todo_responsible: this.state.todo_responsible,
  todo_priority: this.state.todo_priority,
  todo_completed: this.state.todo_completed
}

axios.post('http://localhost:4000/todos/add', newTodo)
.then(res => console.log(res.data));
```